# Tdatetimepicker delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Necesito agarrar el valor de fecha para validar con una ibquery, el siguiente codigo que intento usar para agarrar el valor, pero sin suceso

```
dm_dados.sqlConVenta.ParamByName('datavend').value :=DateTimePicker1.DateTime ;
```

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma solucione

```
dm_dados.sqlConVenta.ParamByName('datavend').Text :=DateToStr (DateTimePicker1.Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Una mejor manera en Delphi de asignar fechas (y cualquier otro valor de tipo de dato) es usar el tipo de dato que estas usando de manera explicita, en este caso:

```
dm_dados.sqlConVenta.ParamByName('datavend').AsDate := DateTimePicker1.Date;
```

Y defines el tipo de dato del parámetro **datavend** como **Date** en las propiedades del objeto **sqlConVenta**.

De la manera que lo resolviste, convirtiéndolo a texto y luego convirtiendo a fecha, puede haber error al pasar los datos por en configuración de como se interpreta por ejemplo '2018-08-07' puede que por configuración de windows se interprete como día 7 del mes de agosto en una computadora y como día 8 del mes de Junio en otra, en cualquiera de los dos casos pasa correcto el valor, pero cuando el día sea mayor de 12 puede que tengas problemas y decenas sino cientos de registros con fechas incorrectas y un error que no sucedía y que ahora tienes que corregir.